# Convert two string list to List of Object use first list index to get the value from Second list

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am slightly confused to get the List of object from two lists of string using map.

Let's take an example:
List 1:

```
var name = arrayListOf("name1","name2","name3")
```

List 2:

```
var lastName = arrayListOf("lastName1","lastName2","lastName3")
```

The data class of Names as below

```
data class Names(
var name: String, 
var lastName: String
)
```

Now i want the List which is combination of name and lastName where we use the name index to get the lastName.

The list of Names as output is below:

```
[Names(name=name1, lastName=lastName1), Names(name=name2, lastName=lastName2), Names(name=name3, lastName=lastName3)]
```

**Request to use the rx kotlin function. By using collection it is easy to solve.**

Comment: Your last sentences sound like you asking how to do this exclusively with Rx, because using the standard library is too easy. Is that right, you want to do this the hard way? With the standard library it would be `val result = name.zip(lastName, ::Names)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#zip) operation:

```
var name = arrayListOf("name1","name2","name3")
var lastName = arrayListOf("lastName1","lastName2","lastName3")
data class Names(
var name: String, 
var lastName: String
)
fun main() {
    println(name.zip(lastName) {n, f -> Names(n, f)} )
}
```

output

```
[Names(name=name1, lastName=lastName1), Names(name=name2, lastName=lastName2), Names(name=name3, lastName=lastName3)]
```

(I don't think you need 'reactive' programming to do this)

There is a shorter way of doing this, using a [constructor reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#constructor-references) as suggested by @Tenfour04 in the comments.

```
name.zip(lastName, ::Names)
```

Comment: Shorter/cleaner: `name.zip(lastName, ::Names)`

Comment: I did not know that. I've added it to the body of the answer, thanks very much.